# VHDL language IDE

Tags: vhdl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Professionnal VHDL IDE ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873536/professionnal-vhdl-ide)

can anybody tell me IDE where i can write VHDL codes?

Comment: What platform do you want to use it on? Windows, Unix, MAC OS?

Comment: I suggest Emacs with electric-mode, it is definitely designed for VHDL.

Answer (score 1):

[Xilinx](http://www.xilinx.com/tools/webpack.htm) and [Altera](https://www.altera.com/download/software/quartus-ii-we) both have IDES available for free download.

At least as of a few years ago when I was using it regularly, the Xilinx software didn't handle updates well at all -- to the point that if you decide to use it, I'd recommend installing it in a virtual machine, and if you ever decide to update it, do a clean install into a fresh VM image.

Answer (score 1):

Your simulator software should have a primitive ID. Xilinx, Altera, Cadence, ModelSim all have primitive VHDL and Verilog IDEs.

Actually, most HDL developers I've worked with don't use the IDEs except for non-HDL related tasks like top-level schematic capture, routing, and analysis.  On the teams I've worked on, Notepadd++ was popular, as well as Vi and Emacs.  I never had a license for it, but one partner company used Visual SlickEdit for all of its editing.  It seemed like a nice tool.

Answer (score 1):

We used Cadence when I was doing my EE undergrad. No complaints (which is rare for university-provided software).